# Gmail Zend_Framework access_token Problem

Tags: php, gmail, zend-mail

I am using zend framework to grab user's email inbox. I got token from the gmail.

```
$_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN'] = serialize($consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, unserialize($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])));
```

and later i got access_token in the $accessToken variable

```
 $accessToken = unserialize($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN']);
```

When i make request to gmail using this $accessToken, every thing is ok.

but when i store this $accessToken in the file or Data base

```
file_put_contents("token.txt",$accessToken);
```

When i make API call to gmail using this access token which i have stored in database or file.

```
$token= file_get_contents("token.txt");

$http  = $token->getHttpClient($oauthOptions); ///Line XXX
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata($http);

$gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);
```

The following Fatal error comes

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getHttpClient() on a non-object in ...myFile.php on line XXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$token is a String here not an Object.

Comment: Then how can i get rid of this problem, i mean how can i make it an object. :

Comment: Try storing the serialized object, then reading your file and using the unserialize method.